# Null values are not writing in "org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel" package

Tags: java, sql, excel, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

```
 Dataset<Row>  SourcePropertSet = sqlContext.read()
             .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
            .option("location", "E:\\XLS\\NEWFILE.xlsx")
             .option("useHeader", "false")
             .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
             .option("inferSchema", "true")
             .option("addColorColumns", "false")
             .load();


SourcePropertSet = SourcePropertSet.repartition(1).select("*")
.write().option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
.format("org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.save("E:\\XLS\\NEWFILE1.xlsx");
```

For the above code is there any other options to consider null values while writing to the xslx format. 
I'm getting **scala.MatchError: null** exception raised, if the particular column contains any null values. 
The Possible solution to resolve is either by putting right logic code or look for .options or is there any other package to do so in .xslx format?

Comment: Can you show Dataset's schema and data?

Comment: I'm loading the data from NEWFILE.xlsx file in which certain data in the particular column contains null values. I had tested for only 3 records manually in that case if the records doesn't contain any null values it successfully writes to excel. But if null values are there, I get the above exception. @abaghe

Comment: Why are using "com.crealytics.spark.excel" for reading and "org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel" for writing? You can use "org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel" for both reading and writing.

Comment: @abaghel  The output which I was getting from org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel is below here which cant be used to match or join columns                                                                               +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|rows                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[col1,,,A1,Sheet1], [col2,,,B1,Sheet1], [col3,,,C1,Sheet1]]                      |
|[[21200490545,,,A2,Sheet1], [5.4756786...

Comment: Schema for Dataset returned by both the libraries are different. You will have to create Dataset  confirming to schema supported by "org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel" before writing and you might need to replace any null value in a row or column with empty String.

Comment: .na().fill(" ");   .show(false); This code resolves the problem. Thank you... @abaghel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.na().fill(" "); .show(false);
```

This code resolves null values issues. In the previous version of “org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel” package

Answer (score 1):

Please check the version of HadoopOffice (currently 1.0.4), in particular for the DS (https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/spark-hadoopoffice-ds). Also, some of the parameters do not exist, so please check the documentation.
It is also faster to create an issue directly with the project on Github to get these things sorted out.